# jquery storing arbitrary element data to be used in callbacks

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'd like to store some arbitrary data on an element for use in an ajax callback like so:

```
$(this).data('my_data', 'hey there');
$(this).click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // $(this).data('my_data') == 'hey there'  :-)
    $.post($(this).attr('href'), '...', function(response) {
        // $(this).data('my_data') == undefined  :-(
    });
});
```

But in the callback 'my_data' is undefined.  Am I just doing something wrong or will this not work?  What is the best way to go about this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this` in the context of the `post` callback function isn't the same this as in the context of the `click` callback.

I'd solve that problem by creating a **closure**:

```
// here `this` == some object

$(this).data('my_data', 'hey there');
$(this).click(function(e) {

    // here `this` == the same object,
    // because the click event handler is called in the context
    // of that object

    // a local variable to be contained in the closure
    var that = this;

    $.post($(this).attr('href'), '...', function(response) {

        // here `this` is something else, but now you can...
        $(that).data('my_data'); 

    });
});
```

The closure magic expands the scope of the local variable `that` into this callback function. This is a bit tricky but useful; have a google on closures in JS for many excellent explanations.

Answer (score 1):

`this` in your callback function for `$.post` will not be bound to your link. You need to create a reference to the link to use in the callback.

```
var $this = $(this);
$this
  .data('my_data', 'hey there')
  .click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // $(this).data('my_data') == 'hey there'  :-)
    $.post($this.attr('href'), '...', function(response) {
        // $this.data('my_data') == 'hey there'  :-)
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

the data() function is a method of the jQuery super object and is not bound to elements. Taken directly from the [jQuery.data() docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/). (I hope I worded that correctly)

```
<script>
    var div = $("div")[0];
    jQuery.data(div, "test", { first: 16, last: "pizza!" });
    $("span:first").text(jQuery.data(div, "test").first);
    $("span:last").text(jQuery.data(div, "test").last);
</script>
```

Comment: This isn't correct, `$.data` is one way to skin the cat but it is perfectly acceptable, if not more convenient, to use `$('div').data`.